# How to make Jenkins hide logs, history, etc on front page?

Tags: jenkins

I want to remove all changes, workspace links and logs from Jenkins front page.

I do not want unauthorized people, bots, etc to have access to this kind of information.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set up your permissions to not allow unauthorized access

### **WARNING:**

***Make sure you have your own user/admin setup will all permission, otherwise you risk locking yourself out.*** If you do, use [information here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) to reset [thanks [Alex]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087370/alex)

To configure anonymous users to not see anything:

- Go to **Manage Jenkins**
- Click **Configure System/Configure Global Security** (depending on your Jenkins/Hudson configuration)
- Under **Access Control -> Security Realm**, you should have either `Matrix-based security` or `Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy`. I will assume you've selected the later.
- Under **User/group to add:** type `authenticated` and click **Add**
- Now, give this group all the permissions that you want them to have.
- Next, under **User/group to add:** type `Anonymous` and click **Add**
- Make sure that none of the permissions are given to this group
- Click **Save**

This way, anonymous (not-logged in) users will not be able to see anything, but authenticated (logged in) users will be able to see what you selected. You can drill-down into more specific user permissions by adding individual users and granting them certain permissions.

**P.S.** The user authentication depends on your **Security Realm** configuration. You can configure to use `Active Directory/LDAP`, or use `Jenkin's own user database`. The former means you don't have to create users in Jenkins, just give them permissions. The later means you've got to create Jenkins's users first through **Manage Jenkins -> Manage Users**

Comment: It worked 1. It is "Configure Global Security" not "Configure System" 2. Please place WARNING on top of anything....I locked myself out :) because by the time I read the warning was too late (fixed with this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security)

Comment: Whoops, sorry, glad you figured out how to reset. I've updated the OP :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote it multiple times..such a rare piece of information.